# use existing field as _id using elasticsearch dsl python DocType

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have class, where I try to set `student_id` as `_id` field in [[image]elasticsearch](/questions/tagged/elasticsearch). I am referring [persistent example](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#persistence-example) from elasticsearch-dsl docs.

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import DocType, String

ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX = 'student_index'

class StudentDoc(DocType):
    '''
    Define mapping for Student type
    '''

    student_id = String(required=True)
    name = String(null_value='')

    class Meta:
        # id = student_id
        index = ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX
```

I tied by setting `id` in `Meta` but it not works.

I get solution as override [`save` method](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/issues/360) and I achieve this

```
def save(self, **kwargs):
    '''
    Override to set metadata id
    '''
    self.meta.id = self.student_id
    return super(StudentDoc, self).save(**kwargs)
```

I am creating this object as

```
>>> a = StudentDoc(student_id=1, tags=['test'])
>>> a.save()
```

Is there any direct way to set from `Meta` without override `save` method ?

Comment: Can you show also how you create a new instance of a `StudentDoc``?

Comment: @Val updated my question with more information.

Comment: @Val, there is [`MetaField`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/blob/master/elasticsearch_dsl/document.py#L27), but I don't know that will be useful here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few ways to assign an id:

You can do it like this

```
a = StudentDoc(meta={'id':1}, student_id=1, tags=['test'])
a.save()
```

Like this:

```
a = StudentDoc(student_id=1, tags=['test'])
a.meta.id = 1
a.save()
```

Also note that before ES 1.5, one was able to [specify a field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/mapping-id-field.html#_path) to use as the document `_id` (in your case, it could have been `student_id`), but this has been deprecated in 1.5 and from then onwards you must explicitly provide an ID or let ES pick one for you.