# elasticsearch not return ttl in fields if not enabled in mappings

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, ttl

I created `index` and `doc` in [[image]elasticsearch](/questions/tagged/elasticsearch). Add mapping for doc.

```
curl http://localhost:9200/test -X POST
{"acknowledged":true}

curl http://localhost:9200/test/student_doc/_mappings -X PUT -d '{
   "student_doc" : {
     "properties" : {
       "name" : {
         "properties" : {
           "student_id" : {
             "type" : "string"
           },
           "tags": {
             "type" : "string"
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }'
{"acknowledged":true}
```

When I create doc, I gave `ttl` for the doc.

```
curl http://localhost:9200/test/student_doc/4?ttl=2500 -X PUT -d '{"student_id": "4", "tags": ["test"]}' -H 'Content-type: application/json'
{"_index":"test","_type":"student_doc","_id":"4","_version":1,"created":true}'
```

When I try to get the `ttl` in `fields`

```
curl http://localhost:9200/test/_search?pretty -X POST -d '{"fields": ["_ttl"]}'
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "test",
      "_type" : "student_doc",
      "_id" : "4",
      "_score" : 1.0
    } ]
  }
}
```

I enable `ttl` in index using new mappings.

```
curl http://localhost:9200/test/student_doc/_mappings -X PUT -d '{
  "student_doc" : {
    "_ttl": {"enabled": true},
    "properties" : {
      "name" : {
        "properties" : {
          "student_id" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "tags": {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Then add new record.

```
curl "http://localhost:9200/test/student_doc/5?ttl=2500&pretty" -X PUT -d '{"student_id": "5", "tags": ["test"]}' -H 'Content-type: application/json'
{
  "_index" : "test",
  "_type" : "student_doc",
  "_id" : "5",
  "_version" : 1,
  "created" : true
}
```

And try to get `ttl` again and it returns the `ttl` in fields.

```
curl http://localhost:9200/test/_search?pretty -X POST -d '{"fields": ["_ttl"]}'
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "test",
      "_type" : "student_doc",
      "_id" : "4",
      "_score" : 1.0
    }, {
      "_index" : "test",
      "_type" : "student_doc",
      "_id" : "5",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "fields" : {
        "_ttl" : -420
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

It is compulsory to enabled `ttl` in mappings to get it effected in document ?

Comment: Yes, `_ttl` is not enabled by default, so you need to enable it in order for TTL to work, but it won't affect already created documents.

Comment: @Val if its not able to set `ttl` then `PUT` call should raise error? Because, I get `created: true`, then I assume it take all my values, is there any way to define that, if something not works, let me know.

Comment: The `ttl` parameter is silently ignored if `_ttl` is not enabled, you won't get any error because of that. It's part of your job to know your mappings and if you enabled TTL or not.

Comment: Is there any performance issue if we enable `ttl` or not ? if we enable `ttl` and planning to use that for document in future then its good or we can enable when we want ?

Comment: You can enable ttl at any time. So given the increased work to support it, you should only enable it when needed.

Comment: Thanks @Val, I will work on this. can you please post this in answer, if someone has same query, he/she can get answer from this.

Comment: @Val this is right or not, I am not sure, but I have another question for elasticsearch http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38533990/use-existing-field-as-id-using-elasticsearch-dsl-python-doctype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `_ttl` is not enabled by default, so you need to enable it in order for TTL to work, but it won't affect already created documents.

Note that the `ttl` parameter is silently ignored if `_ttl` is not enabled in your mapping, you won't get any error because of that. It's part of your job to know your mappings and if you enabled TTL or not.

You can enable `_ttl` at any time, so given the increased work to support it, you should only enable it when needed.