# How can i change the _id for the document django elasticsearch dsl python

Tags: django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

For thew document class i want to change to _id used to be a slug or another option

```
@registry.register_document
class TestDocument(Document):
id = fields.IntegerField(attr='id', multi=True)

name = fields.TextField(
    analyzer=html_strip,
    fields={
        'raw': fields.TextField(analyzer='keyword'),
    }
)

built_area = fields.TextField(
    analyzer=html_strip,
    fields={
        'raw': fields.TextField(analyzer='keyword'),
    }
)
living_area = fields.TextField(
    analyzer=html_strip,
    fields={
        'raw': fields.TextField(analyzer='keyword'),
    }
)

project = fields.ObjectField(properties={
    'name': fields.TextField(),
    'pk': fields.TextField(),
})
```

this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38533990/use-existing-field-as-id-using-elasticsearch-dsl-python-doctype) mentions the meta, but do not works

Answer (score 0):

the right way to do it is using the document function `generate_id`

```
def generate_id(self, object_instance):
    return self.project.id
```

the final document will be:

```
...
project = fields.ObjectField(properties={
    'name': fields.TextField(),
    'pk': fields.TextField(),
})

def generate_id(self, object_instance):
    return self.project.id

class Index:
    # Name of the Elasticsearch index
    name = 'typologies_test'
```